# Run Powershell Script with Multiple Parameters As Variables with If/Else

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script that allows for multiple parameters in any order.I have created another script for users to use who are not tech savy but I need to be able to use their inputs to run the command to start the script and also based on if/else statements. When I try to run the script it gives me an error that says

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
```

But it lists all the variables and the parameters correctly.

If I type out to run the script it runs. The command looks like this:

```
& .\AutoHouse.ps1 -FName FirstName -LName LastName -Country "Country" -Address "Street Name" -Zip #####
```

I did not write AutoHouse.ps1. It is developed by someone else and I am not sure how it handles parameters. I Do know parameters can be added in any order and it will work.

If a users selects a country that is not the USA then address and zip will not be added to the script parameter command for running. Either way if I run it by calling it in my user script it outputs as the above correctly. To have the script run the script is added to a variable called `$CommandRun` . The parameters part is added to a variable as a string called `$RunParams` . So when I call it to run in the user script it looks like this

```
& $CommandRun $RunParams
```

$RunParams is constructed by getting the information form the users as $UserVariable. Then it is added to a $RunParams like this:

$UserVariable = "-FName","$FirstName"
$RunParams = "$RunParams","$UserVariable"

I do this for each variable asked to the user. So it adds the Parameters as it builds all the way down.

This is where I get the error. Am I doing this wrong or do I need to build the script to run a specific way for each eventuality of the options.

Comment: There's a bunch of information missing here - how does `AutoHouse.ps1` handle parameter input, and how exactly are you constructing `$RunParams`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Updated for you. I added information on your questions.

Comment: Just copy-paste the `param(...)` block from `AutoHouse.ps1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.4) your arguments!

Splatting is a technique whereby an array or dictionary of parameter arguments are passed to a command in one go:

```
# prepare named arguments in hashtable
$autoHouseParamArgs = @{
  FName   = 'FirstName' 
  LName   = 'LastName' 
  Country = 'Country' 
  Address = 'Street Name' 
  Zip     = '#####'
}

# splat argument table
.\AutoHouse.ps1 @autoHouseParamArgs
```

(Notice use of `@` instead of `$` as a variable name prefix for the variable we're splatting.)

Now simply populate the hashtable entries conditionally and you're good to go:

```
# create splatting table
$autoHouseParamArgs = @{}

# start populating it based on user input
$autoHouseParamArgs['FName'] = Read-Host 'Input first name: '
$autoHouseParamArgs['LName'] = Read-Host 'Input last name: '

$country = Read-Host 'Input Country [default: France]: '
if ($country) {
  $autoHouseParamArgs['Country'] = $country
}
else {
  $autoHouseParamArgs['Country'] = 'France'
}

# etc ...
```

Comment: So I can build my params based on the answers given? So different variables Splats for how the If statements come out?

Comment: @JukEboX Yes, you simply populate the hashtable entries conditionally before calling the command, I added a basic example

Comment: Awesome that helps a lot. One last question. One of the parameters does not have a variable. Its just called out as -Populated. There is no -Populated Yes as part of the entry. Can I put it in the same way?

Comment: @JukEboX For _switch parameters_ you'll want to supply `$true` for present, so splatting a variable containing the table `@{Populated=$true}` is equivalent to `... -Populated`

Comment: Ok cool! Final question. If I wanted to Write-Host the parameters string do I use $autoHouseParamArgs or do I use @autoHouseParamArgs ?

Comment: @JukEboX What exactly do you mean by `Write-Host the parameters`? Easiest way to "print" a dictionary I can think of is to convert it to JSON, eg `Write-Host ($autoHouseParamArgs |ConvertTo-Json)`. There's no trivial way to "print the resulting commandline" because the parameters are never passed on the command line.